Install an IPA made un Unity to iPhone with Windows
i am trying to install a flappy bird game I made, but i don't know how.
I have an iPhone 8 on 16.7.7 and don't want to jailbreak my phone.
I also have a Windows 10 laptop.
I have not tried anything as I don’t want to mess up my phone.

Whatever workarounds you'll find online, the truth is you still need a Mac to setup your dev account. Even if those workarounds allow you to not be dependent on a Mac, the Mac is still required as a pre-requisite for the initial steps.

ok thanks for that i will not risk any software
